Could not convert string to float: '5,994.98'
You can see here the desired output

Desired Output

Code if you want see = https://github.com/LLNL/mttime/blob/master/examples/notebooks/02_Prepare_Data_and_Synthetics_For_Inversion.ipynb
Error in moment tensor inversion: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64')
I'm trying to create a header file for my data and use it for moment tensor inversion. Code for the header file.
# Create headers
headers = dict(datetime=df["origin"][0],
               longitude=df["lon"][0],
               latitude=df["lat"][0],
               depth=",".join([ "%.4f"%d for d in depths]),
               path_to_data=event_dir,
               path_to_green=green_dir,
               green="herrmann",
               components="ZRT",
               degree=5,
               weight="distance",
               plot=0,
               correlate=0,
              )

# Add station table
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.2f}".format
frame = {"station": station_df[["network","station","location"]].apply(lambda x: ".".join(x),axis=1)}
df_out = pd.DataFrame(frame)
df_out[["distance","azimuth"]] = station_df[["distance","azimuth"]]
df_out["ts"] = int(30)
df_out["npts"] = int(150)
df_out["dt"] = dt
df_out["used"] = 1
df_out[["longitude","latitude"]] = station_df[["longitude","latitude"]]
#print(df_out.to_string(index=False))

# write
with open("mtinv.in","w") as f:
    for key, value in headers.items():
        f.write("{0:<15}{1}\n".format(key,value))
    f.write(df_out.to_string(index=False))
    
!cat mtinv.in

i called the mtinv file for inversion
# Call the Configure object to read the input file and set up the inversion
config = mttime.Configure(path_to_file="mtinv.in")

# Quick look at the attributes
print(config)

But its throwing error like;
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5,994.98'
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:1131, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 2
      1 # Call the Configure object to read the input file and set up the inversion
----> 2 config = mttime.Configure(path_to_file="mtinv.in")
      4 # Quick look at the attributes
      5 print(config)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mttime/core/configure.py:124, in Configure.__init__(self, path_to_file, df, **kwargs)
    121 self._set_attributes(header, **kwargs)
    123 # Read station table
--> 124 self._update_table_index(file)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mttime/core/configure.py:286, in Configure._update_table_index(self, file)
    284 # Read station table
    285 if isinstance(file, str):
--> 286     df = pd.read_table(file, sep=r"\s+", dtype=self._df_dtypes, skiprows=12)
    287 elif isinstance(file, pd.DataFrame):
    288     df = file

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1242, in read_table(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, date_format, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options, dtype_backend)
   1229 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
   1230     dialect,
   1231     delimiter,
   (...)
   1238     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
   1239 )
   1240 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
-> 1242 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:583, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    580     return parser
    582 with parser:
--> 583     return parser.read(nrows)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1704, in TextFileReader.read(self, nrows)
   1697 nrows = validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
   1698 try:
   1699     # error: "ParserBase" has no attribute "read"
   1700     (
   1701         index,
   1702         columns,
   1703         col_dict,
-> 1704     ) = self._engine.read(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
   1705         nrows
   1706     )
   1707 except Exception:
   1708     self.close()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py:234, in CParserWrapper.read(self, nrows)
    232 try:
    233     if self.low_memory:
--> 234         chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
    235         # destructive to chunks
    236         data = _concatenate_chunks(chunks)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:814, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:1036, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:1137, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5,994.98'

The Header File Look Like This
datetime       2022-04-20T05:38:47.987000Z
longitude      -77.7702
latitude       -1.6448
depth          5.0000,184.0000
path_to_data   46778638
path_to_green  46778638/mahesh2013
green          herrmann
components     ZRT
degree         5
weight         distance
plot           0
correlate      0
   station  distance  azimuth  ts  npts   dt  used  longitude  latitude
BK.LIND.00  5,994.98   318.77  30   150 1.00     1    -119.06     36.35
BK.OVRO.00  5,996.00   320.10  30   150 1.00     1    -118.28     37.23
BK.HELL.00  6,013.48   319.12  30   150 1.00     1    -119.02     36.68
BK.PABC.00  6,039.18   316.66  30   150 1.00     1    -120.64     35.16
BK.TSCN.00  6,040.46   317.22  30   150 1.00     1    -120.35     35.54


Just remove the comma

@cup can you tell what code i can use for removing commas and where i need to use

what is your desired output ?

@cup i have posted my code please tell me how to remove commas and where i need to put that code

string.replace(',', '')

@msamedozmen my desired output is like the last image which i have uploaded

@ReblochonMasque and where i need to put this code in the code section

I have created dummy df and tested. You can take look into answer.

Your main problem is having comma in your string. So, you need to find which columns has commas and remove this commas them.
import pandas as pd

data = {'Value1': ['5,994.98', '3,456.78', '7,890.12'],
        'Value2': ['1,234.56', '2,345.67', '3,456.78']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

columns_to_remove_comma = ['Value1', 'Value2']

for col in columns_to_remove_comma:
   df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',', '')

print(df)


Value
0 5,994.98
1 3,456.78
2 7,890.12 output

Do you want comma in your output  ? @op1

if you want to show your float with comma you can add pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.2f}".format after the complete converting  dtype(O) to float64. it will display with comma.  @op1

I don't care about the commas until I get the result should I make full error.

have you seen the error message

Problem came from your df has comma. For that u need to remove commas from your df, and you don't need to convert float64 in df. I'll update code. @op1

Thank you for helping me. I am just new to python. If I am asking silly questions sorry for that.

Firstly you need to find which columns has commas, after find them you need to remove commas from that columns. Then it should be okey. @op1

The distance column have commas

then write df[distance] = df[distance].astype(str).str.replace(",","") @op1

The problem is in the line:
...
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.2f}".format
...

Because pd.to_string is used in line:
...
    f.write(df_out.to_string(index=False))
...

And it uses the display.float_format that you settled.
To stop using a comma as a thousand separator, you have to set the float format like this:
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2f}".format

By doing so, the problem would be solved.

✏ Note:
I have also checked if you can specify the thousand separator while
reading the data with mttime
but it is not possible


this worked but earlier the inversion made 3 files for inversion for 3 components t,r,z but its needs additional files why
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vikas/5 Eq/2 earthquake/examples/notebooks/46778638/mahesh2013/BK.LIND.00.5.0000.ZSS'
